# Problem with chart dividing X axis in 7 hours and displaying values

Tags: vb.net, mschart

I need help to find out a way to fill my chart.

The datatable has 2 columns "DATETIME" and "NUMERIC(10,0)" and has around 6k rows. I would like to divide with "x" in 1,2,....7 hours, but when I execute, it displays a long chart. I don't know how long, but I only see a couple results.

[image]

The result of the query filling the table and displaying result which is very difficult to analyze.

here is the code:

```
Private Sub ButtonTendencia_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonTendencia.Click


    Using cnconexion As New SqlConnection(constring)
        Chart2.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalType = DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Hours
        Chart2.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
        cnconexion.Open()
        Dim d1 As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        Dim d2 As String = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        Dim d3 As Integer = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString
        Dim table As New DataTable
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("select  created_at, salida_1 from salida_a where created_at between '" & d1 & "' and '" & d2 & "' and id_linea =" & d3 & " ", cnconexion)
        da.Fill(table)
        da.Dispose()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table
        Chart2.DataSource = table
        Chart2.Series("Entrada").YValueMembers = "salida_1"
        Chart2.Series("Entrada").XValueMember = "created_at"
        table.Dispose()
    End Using
End Sub
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I'm having trouble interpreting your question.  Could you post the VB code and issue with it?

Comment: yes, let me update the post.

Comment: I may need a little more.  So you're trying to group the records together by hour ranges of the day, in the chart?

Comment: Can't you just set your `Chart2.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1`?  You have the X axis defined in hours, so using a interval of 1 will plot your x axis in hour increments.  Setting it to 24 would plot days.  When changing the scale consider calling `Chart2.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();` to re calculate the scale on the axes.

Comment: How are you storing the `created_at` field in your database?  Is it a datetime?  MSCharts doesn't like timestamps as strings, make sure your database stores it as a datetime so the chart can properly plot it.

Comment: yes it a date time, but im trying just to display the AVG per minute because i hace 2815 rows, and i want to get just the 60 rows, one for each minute.